# Bootstrap табы и container по одной линии

Tags: css

Всем привет.

У меня на странице есть **Bootstrap** сетка сверху  у меня стоит `header` (внутри `container`) фиксированный в котором есть элементы навигации а внизу у меня табы.

Задача состоит в том чтобы `border` табов справой стороны был до конца страницы.
При таких условиях я был вынужден вытащить табы из `container` (**чтобы у них border с правой стороный был на весь экран**) и дать им ширину определенную и `margin-left:auto` чтобы с лева был отступ по сетке.

Проблема заключаетсья в том что я никак не соображу как сделать чтобы во всех экранах (больше 1200 пикселей)  у табов с левой стороны был отступ также как у `header`-а (по одной линии) уже все испробовал.

Попытка 1.
Здесь внизу я задал блоку табов ширину в `90vw` и отступ слева (`margin-left:auto`) автоматически а потом уменьшил ширину экрана и вот что получилось.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попытка 2.
Пробовал дать определенну ширину и справа давать `margin-left:auto` но также неудачно.

Попытка 3.
Пробовал давать только `margin-left` (без ширины ) в **процентах** ,в **vw** , в **rem** ничего не помогло

[**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/DuudeXX8/pen/mzMEaB) ссылка с **SCSS**

Очень прошу помогите ...

```css
.header-middle {
  display: block;
}
.header-middle .middle-content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
.header-middle .middle-content ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.header-middle .middle-content ul li a {
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.header-middle .middle-content ul li.active a {
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
}

.rooms {
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.rooms .tab-container {
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- MiDDLE CONTENT -->
<div class="container header-middle pr-0">
    <div class="middle-content">
      <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Motel</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Rooms & Suits</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Dining</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Offers</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Review</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Blog</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>   
</div>
<!-- MiDDLE CONTENT -->

<section class="rooms">
  <div class="tab-container">
    <!-- Nav tabs -->
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Menu 4</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <!-- Tab panes -->
      <div class="tab-content">

      <div id="home" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
          <div class="container">
                  <h3>HOME</h3>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
              </div>

      </div>
      <div id="menu1" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
          <div class="container">
                  <h3>Menu 1</h3>
                  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
          </div>

      </div> 
      <div id="menu2" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
          <div class="container">
                  <h3>Menu 2</h3>
                  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
          </div>
      </div> 
      <div id="menu3" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
          <div class="container">
                  <h3>Menu 3</h3>
                  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Как должно быть

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуйте запихнуть в контейнер, при редактировании вашего кода, всё выровнялось у меня. `<div class="container">
<section class="rooms"> ......`

Comment: @AlekseyMuratov спасибо за помощь конечно вы не внимательно прочитали.. так как вы сказали выравниваетсья но проблема в том что тогда отступ с лево  обрезаетсья.

Comment: отступ слева для текста в табах должен быть как на скрине?

Comment: @AlekseyMuratov неееет на скрине это как он НЕ должен быть.Отступ должен быть также как у навигации сверху в одной линии с текстом MOTEL

Comment: ну так ведь если оборачиваешь в контейнер отступ такой же как и у навигации, единственное бордер таба не доконца страницы. Добавьте картинку как должно быть.

Comment: @AlekseyMuratov картинку добавил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В таком случае решит сalc:

```
.rooms .tab-container {
    max-width: calc(1140px + (100vw - 1140px)/2);
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Comment: да как до такого можно додуматсья я в шоке.Спасибо вам огромное я дал вам плюсик и принял ответ .

Comment: Пожалуйста, но применяете его медиазапросом свыше этого размера, иначе будут проблемы.

Comment: хорошо спасибо еще раз